# Django Social Registration - Twitter Callback going to example.com

Tags: django, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I have been working through installing django social registration on my webfaction account. So far I have the facebook login working. When I attempt to log in to to twitter I get the correct login page but after choosing "Allow" I am forwarded to the following URL:

http://example.com/social/twitter/callback/.... where "example.com" is the actual URL it is forwarding to.

I have setup the twitter app and have entered a valid oauth callback URL.

I have searched the code on my developer machine for references to "example.com" but have not found any.

Any help nailing this down will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are being redirected to the the site defined via your `Site` app! You should be able to change the domain of your current site in the admin interface!